# No connection string named 'CREntities' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have 2 web-services. The first has a wsHttpBinding binding, the second is the wsDualHttpBinding. Also there is a project that hosts these web services.

[image: Screen branch projects]

[image: My code in host project]

In both services I use EF 6.0. In the service with binding wsHttpBinding, everything works fine. In the service with binding wsDualHttpBinding when accessing the server, an error occurs - "No connection string named 'CREntities' could be found in the application config file."

[image: Place error]

[image: My config file web-service]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I read that the connection string should be added to the hosting project, but then why does everything work to bind wsHttpBinding? I've added a connection thread to the host project, but this did not help, there is an error in the lack of the EF library.

Comment: So which config file did you post?

Comment: @nvoigt, this is a configuration file wsDualHttpBinding. 
It's almost no different from the wsHttpBinding binding

Comment: Post the config file for your executable, the others won't be used anyway.

Comment: @nvoigt, 
I repeat, for binding wsHttpBinding, everything works well, EF 6.0 is also used there and there are no errors when using it.

Comment: Something tells me that the problem is how to implement hosting for wsDualHttpBinding, but I do not know how else to do this, because if you implement hosting as well as wsHttpBinding, an error occurs, that you need to implement the "Session" support.

Comment: EF connection strings have nothing to do with hosting. You will get the exact same error if you change the hosting code in your host project to another binding.

Answer (score 2):

> "No connection string named 'CREntities1' could be found in the application config file."

*That is correct. You need to fix it.*

You can either pass in a value different from your default to the context constructor, or you can rename your connection string from "CREntities" to "CREntities**1**" in your config file.

That said, in the future, please don't post pictures of code, post code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my connection is really called CREntities. This is my mistake in the question. Corrected the mistake.

Comment: "That said, in the future, please don't post pictures of code, post code." 
I understand you, I will not do that any more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so dumb that I just do not have words. No project for hosting needs to be created, Visual Studio will customize everything if you created the WCF Aplication project. A good example of how this works is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA4r-iYCPQY&t=819s

I'm sorry that I wasted your time, I hope someone will need it. (No)